# How to recieve any type of serializable object in Kotlin (Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, serialization

In Java, classes could implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface to allow serializing them, and any method that received serializable data as a parameter would look like so:

```java
public void foo(Serializable data) {
    // ...
}
```

However, in Kotlin, we don't implement an interface to indicate that an object is serializable, instead, we use the `@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable` annotation on a class, meaning that there's no type that a function can take that would cover any serializable data.

I could create my own interface and implement that on any serializable type I create, but that won't work if I wanted to pass an object I didn't write into the function. For example, a `List<T>`, or a `HashMap<K, V>`, etc.

Is there a way to write a function that can receive *any* kind of serializable data?

Comment: You can still use Java Serializable. It's [just not recommended, even in Java](https://foojay.io/today/avoid-java-serialization/). There's no way to specify "type that is Kotlin serializable".

Comment: Worst case you can always create your own interface for anything you want to pass to implement.

Comment: I think you can say that you should pass the modal/POJO.

Comment: you can check this as an example of how to serialize a generic collection that holds value Any: (https://github.com/assafshouval/PolymorphicMapSerializer/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt). or check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

it depends what exactly you need.
But you can for instance have this:

```
public foo<T>(data: T, serializer: KSerializer<T> ) {
       // ...
   }
```